# Elements of $R=S^{-1} \mathbb{C}[ x,y ]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I would like to understand how are the elements of $R=S^{-1} \mathbb{C}[ x,y ]$ where S is the multiplicative set generated by $\{x-a | a \in \mathbb{C} \} \cup \{y-a | a \in \mathbb{C} \}$.

I would like to understand which is the identity element and this kinds of things in order to try to prove if it is a field or not.

Comment: $R$ is the ring of all rational functions in $x$ and $y$ that can be written as fractions of polynomials where the denominator is a product of $x-a$'s and $y-a$'s (for varying $a$). For example, $\dfrac{x^3+xy-7y-\sqrt{3}}{\left(x-1\right)^2\left(y+2\right)} \in R$. The identity element is $1 = 1/1$, as always.

Comment: In order to know if it is a field or not what you need to know is which elements are invertible. Since $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is naturally a subring of $R$ you can try to see which polynomials are invertible in $R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know $S=\langle \{x-a\hspace{0,1cm}|\hspace{0,1cm}a\in \mathbb{C}\} \cup \{y-a\hspace{0,1cm}|\hspace{0,1cm}a\in \mathbb{C}\} \rangle$, what means that if $s\in S$ then it can be written as $s=(x-a_1)\cdot ... \cdot (x-a_n)(y-b_1)\cdot ... \cdot (y-b_m)$ for $a_i, b_j \in \mathbb{C}$ and some $n,m$ positive integers.

Moreover, we know that $$R=S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[x,y] = \{ [f,s]\hspace{0,1cm}|\hspace{0,1cm} f\in \mathbb{C}[x,y] , s \in S \} / \sim$$
where $[f,s]\sim[f',s']$ if and only if $\exists s'' \in S$ such that $s''(s'f-sf')=0$. Since $s\in S$ implies $s\neq0$, we have that $[f,s]\sim[f',s']$ if and only if $(s'f-sf')=0$ if and only if $f/s =f'/s'$.

Knowing that, we need to see if all elements in $R$ have their inverse in $R$. This means $\forall [f,s] \in S^{-1} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, $\exists [f',s'] \in S^{-1} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $[f,s]\cdot[f',s'] \sim  1_R $ where $1_R \sim [t,t]$ for any $t\in S$. This is because $S\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and we need to have the same element in order to have $t/t = 1_R$.

Now consider $[(x+1)(x+y),(x+1)] \in S^{-1} \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. This element is clearly in $R$ since $(x+1)$ has the form we have described before and $(x+1)(x+y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. The inverse of this element should be $[g,j]$ such that $g\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $j\in S$. It must satisfy the following expression: $$[(x+1)(x+y),(x+1)] \cdot [g,j] \sim 1_R$$
That means $(x+1)(x+y)gt=(x+1)jt$, $j=(x+y)g$ where $g\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. But $  \nexists j\in S$ such that $j=(x+y)g$ with $g\in  \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ since $j$ has the form described above.

The element $[(x+1)(x+y),(x+1)]$ has no inverse in $R$. Hence not all elements have their inverse in $R$. Hence $R$ is not a field.